# Ignore onTap() event for Text -> Take onTap() event of parent Row instead

Tags: flutter, events, textfield

I have a `Row` widget. This row has a `Text` as child (in this case, it is a `SelectableText`). The row is embedded into an `InkWell` widget for handling `onTap()` events. This works fine unless I tap the `Text`. In that case the `InkWell` `onTap()` event is not raising.

```
InkWell(
  child: Row (
    children: <Widget> [
      SelectableText(...)
    ]
  ),
  onTap: () => doSth();
)
```

Is it possible to ignore the `Text` for `onTap()` events? My workaround would be to add an `onTap()` event to the `Text` as well with the same code. But, in fact, I want to avoid this replication.

---

**Edit:** In fact, there's also a `Button` widget next to the `Text` widget. Its `onPressed()` event should work as expected, nevertheless.

```
InkWell(
  child: Row (
    children: <Widget> [
      SelectableText(...),
      Button(
        onPressed: () {...}
      )
    ]
  ),
  onTap: () => doSth();
)
```

Comment: @S-Man are you trying to just disable the TextField by catching tap events by InkWell onTap method?

Comment: @Darish Argh... Not TextField, of course. It's a Text(A SelectableTextin this special case)... Sorry for confusion, changed the question

Comment: Are You looking for [`AbsorbPointer`](https://youtu.be/65HoWqBboI8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)

```
InkWell(
  child: Row (
    children: <Widget> [
      IgnorePointer(
        child: SelectableText(...)
     )
    ]
  ),
  onTap: () => doSth();
)
```

Comment: This made it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GestureDetector(
 // behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onTap: () => doSth();
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      SelectableText(...),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: This would ignore the onPressed() events of the Button widget, which is a sibling of the Text widget (see Edit in the question)

Comment: just remove behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque, it should work